# How to adjust geom_text at the top

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code. I want to put geom_text at the top of the geom_vline without overlapping with the line. When I use `vjust = -0.5` it hides the geom_text. How to put geom_text right at the top of geom_vline?

```
library(ggplot2)

# Example data
set.seed(123) # For reproducibility
data <- data.frame(
  category = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 100)),
  value = c(rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 10),
            rnorm(100, mean = 60, sd = 15),
            rnorm(100, mean = 55, sd = 20))
)

# Create histogram with facet wrap
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30, fill = "skyblue", color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~ category) +
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(category = c("A", "B", "C"), mean = tapply(data$value, data$category, mean)),
             aes(xintercept = mean, color = category), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(category = c("A", "B", "C"), mean = tapply(data$value, data$category, mean)),
            aes(label = paste("Mean:", round(mean, 2)), x = mean, y = Inf, color = category),
            vjust = 0.9) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')

# Print the plot
print(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is nothing like the top or the bottom of a `geom_vline` as they stretch from `-Inf` to `Inf`. You could of course use a a `geom_segment` with a `yend` set to a finite value to avoid the overlap. Another option and my personal favorite for this kind of issue would be to switch to `geom_label` where I remove the label outline using `label.size = 0` and set the `fill` color equal to the background fill, which e.g. in case of `theme_grey()` is `"grey92"`. Additionally, `geom_label` allows to add some padding around the label via `label.padding`. Finally, I used `vjust = 1` to align at the top.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30, fill = "skyblue", color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~category) +
  geom_vline(
    data = data.frame(
      category = c("A", "B", "C"),
      mean = tapply(data$value, data$category, mean)
    ),
    aes(xintercept = mean, color = category), linetype = "dashed"
  ) +
  geom_label(
    data = data.frame(
      category = c("A", "B", "C"),
      mean = tapply(data$value, data$category, mean)
    ),
    aes(
      label = paste("Mean:", round(mean, 2)),
      x = mean, y = Inf, color = category
    ),
    vjust = 1, fill = "grey92", label.size = 0,
    label.padding = unit(0.1, "lines")
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting `hjust = 1` will right-align while `hjust = 0` will left-align the text labels. In situations where you need move labels to avoid overlapping with another geom, you can adjust the position further with `nudge_x` (or `nudge_y`).

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Example data
set.seed(123) # For reproducibility
data <- data.frame(
  category = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 100)),
  value = c(rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 10),
            rnorm(100, mean = 60, sd = 15),
            rnorm(100, mean = 55, sd = 20))
)
```

Right-aligned example (`hjust = 1, nudge_x = -1`)

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30, fill = "skyblue", color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~ category) +
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(category = c("A", "B", "C"), mean = tapply(data$value, data$category, mean)),
             aes(xintercept = mean, color = category), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(category = c("A", "B", "C"), mean = tapply(data$value, data$category, mean)),
            aes(label = paste("Mean:", round(mean, 2)), x = mean, y = Inf, color = category), 
            vjust = 0.9, hjust = 1, nudge_x = -1) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Left-aligned example (`hjust = 0, nudge_x = 1`)

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30, fill = "skyblue", color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~ category) +
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(category = c("A", "B", "C"), mean = tapply(data$value, data$category, mean)),
             aes(xintercept = mean, color = category), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(category = c("A", "B", "C"), mean = tapply(data$value, data$category, mean)),
            aes(label = paste("Mean:", round(mean, 2)), x = mean, y = Inf, color = category), 
            vjust = 0.9, hjust = 0, nudge_x = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want the geom_text at the top not on the sides.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, Stefan's suggestions are best.